# Why can't I run my java Hello World program if it is inside a package?

Tags: java, namespaces, package

I created a file called "Hello.java" that looks like this:

```
public class Hello {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello, world!");
        }
}
```

I ran `javac Hello.java`, then `java Hello`, and everything worked as expected.

I then added the line `package testpackage;` to the top of the file, and put it in the directory `/home/matthew/Desktop/hellotest/testpackage`. I put `.:/home/matthew/Desktop/hellotest` in my CLASSPATH, and compiled and ran the same way as before. But now, I get this error:

```
matthew@matthew-laptop:~/Desktop/hellotest/testpackage$ java Hello 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: testpackage/Hello)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
Could not find the main class: Hello. Program will exit.
```

Why did it work on its own, but not in a package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Now that it's in `testpackage`, its name is really `testpackage.Hello`. So go up a directory and do `java` on that.

Answer (score 13):

Go up one directory, and run:

```
java testpackage.Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `java testpackage.Hello`.

Because this is in your classpath, you should be able to run that from any working directory, but refer to it by its full name.