# cmd java not working

Tags: java, classpath

I'm currently learning Java and the use of my command prompt as a compiler. But every time I execute the **java** command followed by my test class "Hello" I get the below error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello (wrong name: hello/Hello)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Now I've checked my "CLASSPATH" environment variable and it is correct as follows: **.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;** I've even tried removing the **.;** from the beginning of the CLASSPATH but it didn't do anything different. Now my **javac** command works just fine by creating a .class version of my .java class. But I just can't get it to actually execute the **java** command.

The name of my class is **Hello** so I typed **javac Hello.java** to compile my file as a class file and it worked. But when I enter: **java Hello** is when I get the above error messages. I've tested the program on my NetBeans IDE that I made it in, and it works perfectly fine with no errors.

What could possibly be going on that would prevent me from executing my java command to run a .class file?

Comment: Have you checked that you have done the correct change directory (`cd`) commands to put you in the folder of the class? Just a thought...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081689/why-cant-i-run-my-java-hello-world-program-if-it-is-inside-a-package?rq=1 this link might helo you

Comment: Yes snickers I'm in the correct directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The name of my class is Hello so I typed javac Hello.java to compile
>   my file as a class file and it worked. But when I enter: java Hello

The most likely problem is that while running your java program you are not putting the complete class name along with the package structure.  It should be run as mentioned here:

```
java packagenhierarchy.Hello
```

Assuming your package name is `com.my.hello` and your main class name is `Hello` then it should be run from the directory containing the top level package as:

```
java com.my.hello.Hello
```

**UPDATE:** As per your comments and knowing the working directory, here is what you should run:

```
java -cp C:\hello\src\hello hello.Hello
```

Comment: I've tried the full path name "java hello.Hello" but it just gives me this error: **Could not find or load main class hello.Hello**

Comment: @subless, From which directory you are running java command? Also have you checked when you used javac command, whether the .class file(s) generated?

Comment: I used cd to navigate to the "hello" directory where the Hello.java file is located, after I used the "javac" command a "Hello.class" file appeared. Then I used "java -cp (path to the hello folder) hello.Hello"

Cause my package is named just: "hello" so my full path would be "hello.Hello" but it still isn't working correctly.

Comment: This won't work unless the main class is in the classpath. Either you set it using the variable `CLASSPATH` or with the option `-classpath` or `-cp`.

Comment: @subless You need to run the java hello.Hello not from the hello directory but from outside that dir. Assuming your hello dir is contained in a some dir called xxx then you need to run the java hello.Hello from xxx dir.

Comment: Ok well the full path to the directory where the files are located is: **C:\hello\src\hello\** so your saying when I use the "-cp" option I should do it from the "src" directory instead of the "hello" directory?

Comment: @subles right! try that.

Comment: It worked! Thank you, so from here on out i'll just call it from the directory before where the .class files are located.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how `java` tool works which is little different than how `javac` works. In order to run a program with `java` command-line command:

1. The class that has the `main(String[] args)` method should be in the classpath.
2. Instead of type `java Hello` you should use the fully qualified name, such as:

```
java com.mypackage.Hello
```

assuming that you set the classpath with the variable `CLASSPATH`. Otherwise, it should be like this:

```
java -cp C:\projects\myprojct\bin com.mypackage.Hello
```

assuming that `bin` is the root directory that has the following hierarchy:

```
bin -
     |
     com -
         |
         mypackage -
                   |
                   Hello.class
```

---

Note that if you don't use neither `CLASSPATH` nor `-cp` nor `-classpath`, then the current directory is by default is in the classpath. In other words, the following should work:

```
cd C:\projects\myprojct\bin
java com.mypackage.Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your current directory is not in the Class path. Try

```
java -cp pathToYourHelloCompiledFile Hello
```

You must have a Hello.class file in your above folder whose path you provide as the class path.

Comment: This won't work if the main class has package name. I am not sure if it will work in case that the main class has no package name.

Comment: I am very sure this works if there is no package name coz I have tried this myself. Not sure with package name though.