# how to run a java program that contains external libraries

Tags: java

say I have a java file foo.java inside the directory bar, that's already compiled

```
bar
   --foo.java
   --foo.class
```

But you still need some libraries in some other dir

```
/opt
    --file1.class
    --file2.class
    subdir
         --file3.class
    subdir2
         --subdir3
              --file4.class
```

Can you simple run the foo program with (inside the bar dirctory)

```
 java foo -cp /opt ?
```

Comment: of course but not working.

Comment: What is the package name of `foo`?

Comment: let's say undeclared in foo.java

Comment: The classes should be placed in the right hierarchy according to the package name. Of course, that is not the case where you don't specify the package name, but it is not recommended to do so. For more details, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18094288/597657

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For windows:

```
java -cp .;pathtojar/jar1;pathtojar/jar2 foo
```

For linux:

```
java -cp .:pathtojar/jar1:pathtojar/jar2 foo
```

For understanding PATH, CLASSPATH etc read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: so can I just specify a root directory as classpath and let it recursively check for children element?

Comment: @Daniel not really, each jar file need to be mentioned with complete directory path.

Comment: the point is that in real life, you may have a complicated dir structure placed under a root directory, and you don't want to specify each one of them in ur -cp option

Comment: what about I have a single source file that imports lots of library codes. How do I specify each library element in an easy way.

Comment: @Daniel wildcard such as * works for multiple jars in a directory. But still you need to add different required dirs to your classpath. For example: java -cp "/lib1/*;/lib2/*"

Comment: say in the source code, it uses the following impport statement: imports dira.1, imports dira.dirb.2, imports dira.dirb.dirc.3, and the list can go on. How can I specify them all in -cp ?

Comment: @Daniel multiple imports maybe from a single jar or jars from a single dir. Use wildcards to reduce the individual jars mentioning int hte claspath.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38271/discussion-between-daniel-and-juned-ahsan)