# SetTwo Class Path For execution of Java Program

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications

I want to Link Two(2)(i.e. for eg: servlet-api.jar and kvclient.jar) .jar file to my program in java through command Prompt.
I Have done it on eclipse and netbeans but now i want to do it through command prompt.

So How can i do it?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: thanks hitham, but i didnt understood it, i am beginner, can you please explain simply?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18094288/597657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Make sure the jars are in proper paths. In Java 6 or later

```
java -cp ".;JAR_NAME.jar;lib/MORE.jar;lib/*" classname
```

Comment: if the .jars are in different folders, and how could i provide paths to them?

Answer (score 1):

```
javac -cp ".;servlet-api.jar;kvclient.jar" YourFile.java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java -classpath classpath1;classpath2
```