# Error: Could not find or load main class SOAPTester

Tags: java, java-7

This should be an easy one I have the following code...

```
package org.me.test;

public class SOAPTester {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
}
}
```

Eclipse compiles the classes and puts them in the bin so I go into the bin folder and I tried...

> java -cp . SOAPTester
>
> java -classpath . SOAPTester

I went back a folder and tried...

> java -cp ./bin/org/me/test/SOAPTester.class SOAPTester

All of these return...

> Error: Could not find or load main class SOAPTester

Can someone tell me what I am missing here? This is on JDK7 and I can confirm the .class file is in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bin folder, try:

```
java -cp . org.me.test.SOAPTester
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to execute following when you're in root folder of `org` folder

```
java org.me.test.SOAPTester
```

More details from [Why can't I run my java Hello World program if it is inside a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081689/why-cant-i-run-my-java-hello-world-program-if-it-is-inside-a-package)